# Select Points in Directx11

Tags: c++, graphics, directx-11

I'm using DirectX11 and DXUT to show point cloud and now want to interactively select points using mouse movement. Specifically when I drag my mouse to draw a rectangle, points in this rectangle would be selected. My method is first convert mouse position to a box, range(-1,1). Then transform the points to projection space using mvp matrix. At last, compare these points' x and y with the box. If in the box, the point is selected.Here is some segments of my code.

```
CModelViewerCamera  g_Camera;

XMMATRIX mView = g_Camera.GetViewMatrix();
XMMATRIX mProj = g_Camera.GetProjMatrix();
XMMATRIX mvp= mWorld * mView * mProj;

XMFLOAT4 p_ext( p.x,p.y,p.z, 1 );
XMVECTOR tmp_p = XMLoadFloat4(&p_ext);
tmp_p = XMVector4Transform( tmp_p, XMMatrixTranspose(mvp) );
XMStoreFloat4( &p_ext, tmp_p );
float x = p_ext.x;
float y = p_ext.y;

if ( x > bottom_left.x && x < up_right.x &&
        y > bottom_left.y && y < up_right.y )
{
    //In box, Mark using other color
}
```

However when I run my code, I find that points transformed to projection space is not in range(-1,1). Can anyone point out my mistake, or just give me another way to achieve the goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mvp` matrix is supposed to apply the model transformation, the view transformation and the projection transformation in that order. For the `mvp` matrix to do this it needs to be calculated like this:

```
mvp = mProj * mView * mWorld
```

Second why are you transposing the matrix `mvp`? `DirectX` is using row-major matrices and `XMMatrix` is also row-major so there shouldn't be a reason to transpose the `mvp` matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, I should write it in inverse order, and secondly I forgot to divide w component to make x,y in (-1,1).